# Python Pandas max value in a group as a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping, pandas-groupby

I am trying to calculate a new column which contains maximum values for each of several groups. I'm coming from a Stata background so I know the Stata code would be something like this:

```
by group, sort: egen max = max(odds)
```

For example:

```
data = {'group' : ['A', 'A', 'B','B'],
    'odds' : [85, 75, 60, 65]}
```

Then I would like it to look like:

```
    group    odds    max
     A        85      85
     A        75      85
     B        60      65
     B        65      65
```

Eventually I am trying to form a column that takes `1/(max-min) * odds` where `max` and `min` are for each group.

Answer (score 47):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```
df['max'] = df.groupby('group')['odds'].transform('max')
```

This is equivalent to the verbose:

```
maxima = df.groupby('group')['odds'].max()
df['max'] = df['group'].map(maxima)
```

The `transform` method aligns the `groupby` result to the `groupby` indexer, so no explicit mapping is required.

Answer (score 4):

Using the approach from jpp above works, but it also gives a "SettingWithCopyWarning". While this may not be an issue, I believe the code below would remove that warning:

```
df = df.assign(max = df.groupby('group')['odds'].transform('max')).values
```

Comment: Be careful, you are assigning a NumPy array (`values` attribute of a dataframe) to `df`. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: I had to convert the NumPy Array to DF again. Still, this was a much faster solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['max'] = df.group_col.map(lambda x: df.groupby('group_col').odds.max()[x])
```

Comment: It will be better if you can explain a bit your answer. Only code is not acceptable on SO.

Comment: The lambda function does a groupby on group_col and returns the maximum values of the odds column in each group. The indices of these returned values are the name of the group they belong to. So for each element in group_col, we map the appropriate maximum value by doing (lambda x (the group name): groupby_returns_max_values [x]).

Comment: A `lambda` function isn't necessary here; you *could* use a series mapping directly. But, better, use `groupby` + `transform` (as show in another answer).

Comment: The answer from  @jpp is much faster for large dataframes