# Comparing one row's value against multiple in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to find the "best in class", with each class being a whole dollar amount in `prices` and "best" being maximum `value` like so:

```py
example = pd.DataFrame({    
    "values": [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8,8,8,8,8, 9 ],
    "prices": [1.1, 2.2, 3.31, 3.32, 3.33, 4.1, 4.2, 5.1, 6.1, 6.2, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4, 8.5, 9.1]
})
```

Is there a way to compare the value of a column against multiple? Perhaps something like:

```py
example["is_best"] = np.where(example["prices"] < all(example[example[values]])
```

Expected output:

```
    values  prices  is_best
0   1       1.10    1
1   2       2.20    1
2   3       3.31    1
3   3       3.32    0
4   3       3.33    0
5   4       4.10    1
6   4       4.20    0
7   5       5.10    0
8   6       6.10    1
9   6       6.20    0
```

**Caveat**: There will be other columns with varying data in them.

Comment: Are you just wanting to group by "values" and find the maximum of "prices" for each group?

Comment: It sounds like `example['is_best'] = example.groupby('values').transform('max')` [Python Pandas max value in a group as a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35640364/15497888)

Comment: I'm trying to find the minimum price for each value, aka the lease amount of money to spend for the most bang

Comment: Then just do `'min'`? `example['is_best'] = example.groupby('values')['prices'].transform('min')`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're wanting to preserve your dataframe structure other than just ID'ing the max in each group. In this case, transform and np.where as you suggested do the trick.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({    
    "values": [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8,8,8,8,8, 9 ],
    "prices": [1.1, 2.2, 3.31, 3.32, 3.33, 4.1, 4.2, 5.1, 6.1, 6.2, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4, 8.5, 9.1]
})

df['is_best'] = np.where(
    df['prices']==df.groupby('values')['prices'].transform('min'),
   1, 0
)
```

Output:

```
values  prices  is_best
0   1   1.10    1
1   2   2.20    1
2   3   3.31    1
3   3   3.32    0
4   3   3.33    0
5   4   4.10    1
6   4   4.20    0
7   5   5.10    1
8   6   6.10    1
9   6   6.20    0
10  7   7.10    1
11  7   7.20    0
12  7   7.30    0
13  8   8.10    1
14  8   8.20    0
15  8   8.30    0
16  8   8.40    0
17  8   8.50    0
18  9   9.10    1
```